# How to find last key in orm object of Kohana

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I want to display the all users name with  ,(comma) and dont want comma after last name.

Code:

```
$users = ORM::factory('users')->find_all();

foreach($users as $user){
   echo $user->name . ',';
}
```

This gives output

`jimy, mark, larry,`

But i dont want the last comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$users = ORM::factory('users')->find_all();

echo implode(',', $user->as_array(NULL, 'name'));
```